# User-Defined Option Argument for Custom Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-defined-functions

Thanks in advance,

I want to write a new Matlab function code with different options for sub-algorithms for two distinct steps dealing the input argument/s. An example of one solution can be illustrated by use of switch-case statement such as:

```
function Return = Calculator(input,option1,option2)

switch option1 

  case 'Algorithm1_Opt1'
    sub=f_Algorithm1_Opt1(input)

  case 'Algorithm2_Opt1'
    sub=f_Algorithm2_Opt1(input)

end

switch option2

  case 'Algorithm1_Opt2'
    Return=f_Algorithm1_Opt2(sub)

  case 'Algorithm2_Opt2'
    Return=f_Algorithm2_Opt2(sub)

end
```

**My question:** is there a way to specify custom options structure for an user-defined function as in optimset like;

```
options = optimset('param1',value1,'param2',value2,...)
```

such as;

```
options = optimset('Display','iter','TolX',1e-8)
```

**So at last,** I want to call my function as;

```
Return_exp=Calculator(input_exp,'option1','Algorithm1_Opt1','option2','Algorithm2_Opt2')
```

Regards.

Comment: [`inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html)

Comment: Use the above or write yourself a loop and use `switch`. The argument of `case` can be a cell of strings. That should be helpful in case you forget the option names after a while. You can also use `varargin` for optional options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out you can use the `inputParser` class or `varargin`. The `inputParser` implementation is sometimes too simplistic for coding complex problems. I usually prefer using `varargin` in these circumstances. Below are some templates I used.

For parameter parsing in functions:

```
function output=myfunc(requiredArg1,requiredArg2,varargin)

%% Parse Param-Value Inputs
PARAM_NAMES={'name1','name2'};
PARAM_VALUES={value1_default,value2_default};
n=1;
N=numel(varargin);
while n<N
    % Read parameter name.
    if ischar(varargin{n}) && isrow(varargin{n})
        tf=strcmpi(varargin{n},PARAM_NAMES);
        if any(tf)
            % Set parameter value.
            PARAM_VALUES{tf}=varargin{n+1};
        else
            error('Unrecognized parameter name.');
        end
    else
        error('Unrecognized input. Parameter name must be a string.');
    end
    n=n+2;
end
if n<=N
    warning('An extra input argument was provided, but is ignored.');
end

%% Program

end
```

For parameter parsing in constructors for handle classes:

```
methods

    function obj=ObjectName(requiredArg1,requiredArg2,varargin)

    %% Set Object Properties Using Param-Value Inputs
    n=1;
    N=numel(varargin);
    while n<N
        % Read property name.
        if ischar(varargin{n}) && isrow(varargin{n})
            mp=findprop(obj,varargin{n});
            if isempty(mp)
                error('''%s'' is not a property of the %s class.',varargin{n},class(obj));
            elseif strcmpi(mp.SetAccess,'public')
                obj.(varargin{n})=varargin{n+1};
            else
                error('Denied access to set the ''%s'' property.',varargin{n});
            end
            n=n+2;
        end
    end
    if n<=N
        warning('An extra input argument was provided, but is ignored.');
    end

    %% Program

    end

end
```

The first template can be also be used for parameter parsing in constructors for value classes by setting `PARAM_NAMES=properties(obj)`.

Comment: Thank you heriantolim. I will make use of Parameter parsing (Param-Value Inputs).